# jquery function sticky not working when end of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, sticky

As you can see on [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rkty0L3h/), the problem is when its scrolling on the first section it works but when it reach the end of the first section it should disappear and appear again on the second section

I have a working program but it's using "position:sticky" but I like to make similar effect but without using "position:sticky "

My working fiddle when using position:sticky [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dyc19oxL/)

```js
var $sticky = jQuery('.sticky');


jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
  $sticky.each(function() {
    const $this = jQuery(this);
    const stickyTop = $this.offset().top;
    const stickyBottom = stickyTop + $this.outerHeight();

    const $stickyTo = $this.parent();
    const stickyToTop = $stickyTo.offset().top;
    const stickyToBottom = stickyToTop + $stickyTo.outerHeight();

    if (stickyBottom >= stickyToBottom) {
      if (scroll < stickyTop) {
        //$sticky.addClass('fixed').removeClass('abs');
      } else {
        //$sticky.addClass('abs');
      }
    } else if (scroll > stickyToTop) {
      $(this).addClass('stuck');
    } else if (scroll < stickyToTop) {
      $(this).removeClass('stuck');
    }

  })

});
```

```css
.stickyTo {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.content {
  height: 400px;
}

.sticky {
  display: none;
}

.stuck {
  display: block;
}

.row {
  background: #ccc;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
}

.abs {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br>
<div class="grid-container">

  <div class="top_picks"></div>
  <div class="stickyTo">
    <div class="sticky" style="position:fixed; top: 100px;background:yellow">stick and unstuck on end of parent container</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
  </div>
  <br><br><br>
  <div class="top_picks"></div>
  <div class="stickyTo">
    <div class="sticky" style="position:fixed; top: 100px;background:yellow">another stick and unstuck on end of parent container</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- end grid-container -->

<div style="height:800px;"></div>
```

Comment: You mean _without using   position: fixed;_ or what? Sticky is just a class name here. Also your fiddle is loading jQuery twice

Comment: no, without using position:sticky

Comment: But there is no position:sticky in your example

Comment: there is, here is the fiddle that uses position:sticky https://jsfiddle.net/dyc19oxL/

Comment: I would to have that same approach but not use position:sticky see here https://jsfiddle.net/rkty0L3h/

Comment: Sorry then I missed one fiddle when I made your question more readable